# Installing a Content Provider with an application

Tags: android

I have Content Provider that is used in several applications. I need that this Content Provider will be installed with one of the applications that use it.

I have tried:
make `CP by the library` +
to add to the Manifest of one of the apps:

```
<application >
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.app.test"
            android:name="TestProvider" >
        </provider>
    </application>
enter code here
```

But it seems doesn't work.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: Don't get your question.

Comment: I need to install ContentProvider and App that uses this ContentProvider using only one apk of the App.

Answer (score 2):

An example of a QueryProvider for Suggestions

```
import android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider;

public class QueryProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
    public final static String AUTHORITY = "your_package.QueryProvider";
    public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES | DATABASE_MODE_2LINES;

    public QueryProvider() {
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }
}
```

in the Manifest.xml (inside the applicaction tag)

```
<provider 
     android:name="QueryProvider"
     android:authorities="your_package.QueryProvider" 
/>
```